# How to add more ciphers to RabbitMQ?

Tags: encryption, openssl, erlang, rabbitmq

When I check the list of ciphers what RabbitMQ/Erlang supports, I see the following:

```
[root@node ~]# rabbitmqctl eval 'ssl:cipher_suites().'
[{dhe_rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha256},
 {dhe_dss,aes_256_cbc,sha256},
 {rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha256},
 {dhe_rsa,aes_128_cbc,sha256},
 {dhe_dss,aes_128_cbc,sha256},
 {rsa,aes_128_cbc,sha256},
 {dhe_rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {dhe_dss,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,aes_256_cbc,sha},
 {dhe_rsa,'3des_ede_cbc',sha},
 {dhe_dss,'3des_ede_cbc',sha},
 {rsa,'3des_ede_cbc',sha},
 {dhe_rsa,aes_128_cbc,sha},
 {dhe_dss,aes_128_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,aes_128_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,rc4_128,sha},
 {rsa,rc4_128,md5},
 {dhe_rsa,des_cbc,sha},
 {rsa,des_cbc,sha}]
...done.
```

However my OpenSSL (1.0.1e-fips) seem to be supporting more than this.

My question is, how can I add more ciphers to RabbitMQ to use? To be more specific, I would like to use GCM ciphers.

If I add one to the configuration file, for example:

```
{dhe_rsa,aes_128_gcm,sha256}
```

it simply won't work like it does with the others.

Comment: Please show your RabbitMQ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the newest version of erlang, you can check if some older versions supported this cipher, maybe it was deleted in some update.

Comment: It looks like it is the case, but the other way around: the current version of Erlang doesn't support these ciphers, so an upgrade is required to at least OTP 18.